# Error When Building APK From Flutter Project

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, apk

I faced a problem when I am trying to build the APK from my flutter project.
I used appicon.co to create the app icons.

```
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Initializing gradle...                                              1.4s
Resolving dependencies...                                           6.4s
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  Output:  D:\projects\e-cal app\ECAL appication\ecal\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

  Command: C:\Users\DELL\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\dc6524cdbb29b6d93306387944c512dd\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
          -o \
          D:\projects\e-cal app\ECAL appication\ecal\build\app\intermediates\res\merged\release \
          D:\projects\e-cal app\ECAL appication\ecal\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      76.4s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

How to fix that issue? Can someone help please.

Answer (score 0):

I not to sure, but when building you should try to build app bundle, as it doesn't take up as much room and will make people more likely to get your app.